# I am trying to print the method findAverage in the main method, can anyone tell me how to fix

Tags: methods, printing

```
public class Grade {
    private int [] array = {2,3,1,4,5,7,1};

    public int findSum() {
        int sum;
        sum = 0;
        for(int i =0; i <array.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum +array[i];
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public double findAverage() {
        double average;
        average = findSum()/array.length;
        return average;
    }
}

class ExamClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double answer;
        answer = findAverage();
        System.out.println("Average of all elements in the array is" + answer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main you have to create a instance of the class

**Create instance**

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
    {  
        double answer;  
        Grade g= new Grade();
        answer = g.findAverage();  
        System.out.println("Average of all elements in the array is" + answer);  
    }
```

Also you can make the method static